# Firebird CTE result dataset with insert statement

Tags: sql, firebird, common-table-expression

I do have the difficulties with the following code I couldn't find where to place the insert statement in that code where it will insert the returned values from the CTE.

```
insert into ntm (num,comb,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
with CTE as (
  SELECT a.ELM_NUM as num, 
         a.N_1 as N1,
         (trim('1.4*'||a.COMBO)||' + ' || '1.6*'||b.COMBO) as com2,
         b.ELM_NUM as num2 
    FROM NTM a cross join ntm b 
    where ((a.Combo='dead' and b.combo='live') or (a.Combo='dead' and b.combo='live')) and a.ELM_NUM=b.ELM_NUM) 

  select num, num2, trim(trim(com2)||' + '||trim(d.combo)), N1, 1.4*N1
    from CTE cross join ntm d
    where (d.elm_num = cte.num) and (position('X',combo)>0 or position('Y',combo)>0 )
```

error raised by FlameRobin Engine "Token unknown - line 1, column 27
0

```
CREATE TABLE NTM
(
ELM_NUM Integer NOT NULL,
COMBO Char(40) NOT NULL,
N_1 Double precision,
N_2 Double precision,
V2_1 Double precision,
V2_2 Double precision,
V3_1 Double precision,
V3_2 Double precision,
M2_1 Double precision,
M2_2 Double precision,
M3_1 Double precision,
M3_2 Double precision,
MT_1 Double precision,
MT_2 Double precision
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the result of an select statement by adding `INSERT INTO <table> (<column>[, <column>]*)` before the select statement (including the `WITH`). So If you have a query:

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT 4 AS ID, 'Item 4' AS NAME FROM RDB$DATABASE
) 
SELECT ID, NAME 
FROM a
```

And you want to insert into a table `ITEMS` with columns `ID` and `NAME`:

```
INSERT INTO ITEMS (ID, NAME) 
WITH a AS (
    SELECT 4 AS ID, 'Item 4' AS NAME FROM RDB$DATABASE
) 
SELECT ID, NAME 
FROM a
```

This works on Firebird 2.5, but I assume it also works in Firebird 2.1.

**Based on your edit**:

Your syntax is simply wrong: `insert into ntm (num,comb,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)` is invalid: you don't have a columns `num` and `comb` in table `ntm`, and specifying `0` as a column name is illegal. It seems you are confusing the `INSERT` columnlist with a value-list.

The syntax of an `INSERT` is:

```
INSERT INTO <object> [(col [, col …])]
{VALUES (<val> [, <val> …]) | <select_expr>}
```

You try to use something like:

```
INSERT INTO <object> (<val> [, <val> …])
<select_expr>
```

Assuming you only want to insert the `num` (into `ELM_NUM`) and the `trim(trim(com2)||' + '||trim(d.combo))` (into `COMBO`) columns from your select, you should use:

```
insert into ntm (ELM_NUM,COMBO)
with CTE as (
    SELECT a.ELM_NUM as num, 
         a.N_1 as N1,
         trim('1.4*'||a.COMBO)||' + ' || '1.6*'||b.COMBO as com2,
         b.ELM_NUM as num2 
    FROM NTM a cross join ntm b 
    where (a.Combo='dead' and b.combo='live' or a.Combo='dead' and b.combo='live') and a.ELM_NUM=b.ELM_NUM
) 
select num, trim(trim(com2)||' + '||trim(d.combo))
from CTE cross join ntm d
where d.elm_num = cte.num and (position('X',combo) > 0 or position('Y',combo) > 0)
```

Note that I removed the other columns from the select as you are not inserting those (the number of columns in the select list must match the number of columns in the insert column list).

If you want the remaining columns to be 0, you either need to add a `DEFAULT 0` to the table definition, or you need to list all columns and add a `0` value in your select list for each of those additional columns.

Comment: I'm using the Firebird 2.1 and FlameRobin to execute the SQL queries. Adding the insert "insert into ntm values(num,comb,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)"  before "with" statement  still raises some erratic errors e.g. <Token unknown - line 2, column 1 with >it seems that server doesn't understand the syntax, BTW I also noticed that I can not insert the records with your syntax, instead I must use values statement. Do all of these clues give anything about the source of discrepancy?

Comment: You can't use `INSERT ... VALUES` when combined with a `SELECT`, that is a syntax error.

Comment: Ok but then syntax w/o values never works engine raises another errors for zeros in the insert statement. Please see the declaration of NTM table in original post.

Comment: Include the exact query you try to use for the insert and the syntax error in your question.